# jmeter response time got increased by 4times after java upgrade

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter 3.3 for executing performance script. Currently Java got upgraded in server from 1.7 to 1.8. Now while executing script on submitting SSO stub page for doing SSL handshake where there is redirection from one end point URL to another exists, its taking more than 60secs to redirect, whereas manually it hardly takes15-20 secs. Same script took hardly 10secs before java upgrade. Any idea how to resolve this Jmeter issue

Comment: It is always recommended to use latest Jmeter4.0 and java. Try after upgrading and see it you still have the issue.

Comment: I also tried the execute the same script in 4.0, but same time delay is there.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to [JEP-115](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/115) which adds GCM algorithm which is on one hand secure and on another is quite slow or other [security enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html)

If it impacts your tests you can disable the algorithm by taking the next steps:

1. Create `java.security` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Add the next line to it:

   ```
   jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3,GCM
   ```
3. Then add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   java.security.properties=java.security
   ```

Also consider upgrading to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) as you should be always using the latest JMeter version according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: I tried as suggested in Jmeter 3.3, but with same result. No improvement in response time.

Comment: I also downloaded 4.0 and done the same changes as suggested. But still the response time is same in 4.0 also. No improvements.

Comment: Please suggest if any other solution is there